# how to show design/text tab in xml file in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I want to make a menu in android studio. when I create a new android resource file in res folder the design/text tab is not show in xml file and I can't put menu item in it. but in other xml files this tab(text/design) is active. my android studio version is 2.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems on the layout(and previously the code was running), you should create a new project because sometimes the layout have some rendering problems.
If you want to add an EditText(or similar components using xml code) you can type, for example:
    `<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_lastname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            />`
So the components you added will be on the layout.

Comment: thank for answer. I put 2 item in menu in xml file but when I run the project this error happen:getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaab4f9a0 also error -75. @P.Halley

Comment: I never had this error.. try to update Android Studio to the last version and try again.